# How to loop all files in powershell to zip every file to its old name

Tags: powershell, winrar

I'm trying to zip every file in a directory but I can't seem to get it to use the directory or the old file name. It needs to delete the old file so that it's protected in the zip file.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\Backuptest\input\*" | 
ForEach ($filename in $files) { 
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    & "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -m0 -hps8Cs7y7RfLjYgYb -k -df $filename.rar
    }
```

Comment: It just adds all of the files in System32 instead of the directory I provided. It does however get 1 of the names right. But it doesn't put every single file in it's own .zip

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it, that was exactly what I needed. And I've learned a bit on how to use it aswel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### PowerShell Rar Archive, Encrypt, and Delete Multiple Files in a Folder

### <sup>With **Powershell** and the below syntax I....</sup>

- set the variables for the **source** directory up top to tell it the
  ***path*** to get the files to compress, and
- set the variable for the  **destination** directory telling it the **path** *for the encrypted archive rar files are to be output to*,

so this makes it a little more explicit than it was before telling it where the files will go before deleting them (no more **`/System32`**, etc,).

This way uses the [ForEach (method)](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html) to get the file object filename per file in the source directory and then one-by-one it will create a new rar encrypted file with the same file name as the non-encrypted [source] file and append the .rar to the end of it. (*E.g. `test123.txt` will become `test123.txt.rar` encrypted and then `test123.txt` will be deleted.*)

I think your issue was either <sup>(1.)</sup>the syntax of the [rar](http://ss64.com/bash/rar.html) commands not being correct, or <sup>(2.)</sup>not having the destination in the rar commands for the output location and that running implicitly from that directory and just outputting there.

---

### Powershell Script

```
$Source      = Get-ChildItem "D:\Backuptest\input"
$Destination = "D:\Backuptest\input"
$RarApp      = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" 

ForEach ($files in $Source) { 
    & $RarApp a $($Destination + $files.Name + ".rar") $($files.FullName) -m0 -hps8Cs7y7RfLjYgYb -k -df
    }
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**ForEach**](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)
- [**ForEach (method)**](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html)
- [**rar**](http://ss64.com/bash/rar.html)